# nix package manage: can't install firefox

Tags: software-installation, firefox, nix

Tried to install firefox, at first the dependent packages were installed correctly. But at the end I got the following errors:

```
$nix-env -i firefox-67.0.1
...
post-installation fixup
Moving /nix/store/qx4w4841grng03q819hmaj315j7a9w6r-compiler-rt-7.1.0/include to /nix/store/a0dxd8aiqvpfxwlpv44d0xbpkmcxcq0g-compiler-rt-7.1.0-dev/include
Removing empty /nix/store/qx4w4841grng03q819hmaj315j7a9w6r-compiler-rt-7.1.0/ and (possibly) its parents
strip is /nix/store/ah81jgj71sr7nmvy4pc6x89pgpr6ygvk-binutils-2.31.1/bin/strip
shrinking RPATHs of ELF executables and libraries in /nix/store/a0dxd8aiqvpfxwlpv44d0xbpkmcxcq0g-compiler-rt-7.1.0-dev
strip is /nix/store/ah81jgj71sr7nmvy4pc6x89pgpr6ygvk-binutils-2.31.1/bin/strip
patching script interpreter paths in /nix/store/a0dxd8aiqvpfxwlpv44d0xbpkmcxcq0g-compiler-rt-7.1.0-dev
checking for references to /build/ in /nix/store/a0dxd8aiqvpfxwlpv44d0xbpkmcxcq0g-compiler-rt-7.1.0-dev...
builder for '/nix/store/75sxcn605fsqr3jgbf70chn8550rvk4j-compiler-rt-7.1.0.drv' failed to produce output path '/nix/store/qx4w4841grng03q819hmaj315j7a9w6r-compiler-rt-7.1.0'
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/d6rh69f4gik90sm24p422gf3zpws6svb-clang-wrapper-7.1.0.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
copying path '/nix/store/p7dyx7mwj4llimn0ydm6dkw910j81sgz-gtk+-2.24.32-dev' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/ihd6b877m513q4aq9q0gddxgl7b6lw2b-firefox-unwrapped-67.0.1.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
copying path '/nix/store/zwrn3cwjl7gs7kaj872pyzzrd0j98kbr-gtk+3-3.24.8-dev' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/r85ddzbfic2jvypaskj6brbd51fy64h1-firefox-67.0.1.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
error: build of '/nix/store/r85ddzbfic2jvypaskj6brbd51fy64h1-firefox-67.0.1.drv' failed
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't in firefox build itself but in `llvmPackages.compiler-rt`.  I think it's better to use the issue tracker for this kind of problems: https://github.com/nixos/nixpkgs/issues

... but let me try to help here anyway.  The whole firefox builds show OK on the build farm in the past few weeks ([master](https://hydra.nixos.org/job/nixpkgs/trunk/firefoxPackages.firefox.x86_64-linux/all), [19.03](https://hydra.nixos.org/job/nixos/release-19.03/nixpkgs.firefoxPackages.firefox.x86_64-linux/all)), so: (1) you might try to figure out why the binaries from Hydra aren't used (in case that's not intentional by you) – I can see the path isn't in there so you may have unusual/unexpected source version or override; (2) you may try to find why it fails locally... my first guess would be that you have sandboxing disabled and that exposes some impurity in the  build.

Comment: "you might try to figure out why the binaries from Hydra aren't used" - how to do it?

Comment: I would start by checking if your nixpkgs configuration is what you expect.  In particular the expressions that get evaluated (`nix-channel` usually).